# EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android

I want to run my application in two different Android devices. First is 4.0.3 Android device and the second is 4.1.2. The first device, the application executed successfully, but in the second, LogCat displays me EACCES (Permission denied). Why???

I have already added the permissions. My manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidjnetpcaptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.pemission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Default" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Code, stacktrace and target SDK version would be relevant information here. Also note that the manifest snippet you posted is malformed and should not even compile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the error I had to run the command chmod 777 to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Check you permission. it should be outside of application tag

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        ...

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes, it is located outside of application tag

Comment: Are you sure that second device is connect complete with your machine. It happens if you sd card is locked

Comment: Yes, I found the error I had to run: chmod 777 to the file that I want to open.